# Setting up fingerprint reader in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, fingerprint-reader

Following instructions from help.ubuntu.com about setting up fingerprint login by selecting Activities>Users I do not get a FingerPrint option in Authentication & Login.
libpamd-fprintd is installed on the system.
How to I get the FingerPrint option?

Comment: Some systems require “extra steps” to get the fingerprint reader working properly. What kind of computer are you using? Are you able to save fingerprints?

Comment: The computer is an HP Envy laptop. The fingerprint reader worked when I had Windows 10 on it, bu I got rid of that and have only Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be a lot of support for the fingerprint reader on HP Envy notebooks. [This thread](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Linux-driver-for-fingerprint-reader/m-p/6671531#M454727) has a script to show if the reader is an ACPI device. If it is, then there’s little chance of Linux support without HP’s direct involvement.

Comment: Tried following the script in 'This thread' but got nothing similar to it's output. so I don't know if the HP Envy is the same as the HP in the thread.

Comment: HP tech support cannot tell me if it is an ACPI device. They say it is a generic device and the driver is installed and supported only by WIndows 10